# Query on same entity in strapi v4

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have a **strapi** project `v4.3.8` and I find myself in difficulty by filtering an entity ([here doc](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/filters-locale-publication)). In detail I have the entities `users` and `orders` with the relation `0 -> N`.

I need to retrieve all those users that have one order with `year 2023` **AND** `status COMPLETED`.

I tried with this query:

```
{
  filters: {
    orders: {
      status: "COMPLETED",
      year: 2023
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because it checks these properties also on different orders. For example it returns the users that have order 1 with status COMPLETED but year 2022 and order 2 with year 2023 but status PENDING. So it checks if there are orders with those properties not necessary on same entity.

I need these properties to verify on the ***same entity***. Do you have any idea or clue on what should I try?

Comment: Have you tried using `$and` operator?